# How to set a first character is the capital in string

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am new to Swift.  I'm implementing a login page.

I have multiple textfield in a view controller. When I enter the text in a textfield the first later should changed to a capital.

I know keyboard selection in keyboard setting, but my aim is even that no matter how the user enters text the first word should be capitalised.

I have tried so many ways, but I haven't found any solution

Comment: Do you want to make the word all caps or just the first letter? Doing this for a password field is a bad idea as it reduces password entropy.

Comment: @Paulw11 i want first letter only capital in a name textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChanged(sender:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    @objc func valueChanged(sender: UITextField){
        sender.text = sender.text?.capitalized
    }
```

Comment: This will capitalize all the words though, not only the first character. It will also mess up cursor behavior when editing.

Answer (score 0):

In **SWIFT 3** -

```
textFiled.autocapitalizationType = .sentences //  first character of First word of every sentence is Capital
textFiled.autocapitalizationType = .words //first character of every word will be Capital
textFiled.autocapitalizationType = .allCharacters //All Characters will be Capital
```

In **Storyboard**

[image]